# How to send variable (dynamic value) at @findby in POM using java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, page-objects, pom

How to send variable with dynamic value at `@findby` in POM using java like -

`//div[@class='item']/div[@class='containerbody'][@columnid=' "+i+" ']/div/div[contains(@class,'swimLaneheader')]
where i is the variable`

Please provide me some examples that includes `@FindBy`, with the dynamic declaration and dynamic value sending.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Since Java annotations does not allow dynamic parameterization.

For more details [check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly using `@FindBy` but the same effect could be achieved with something like that:

```
private static final String ROW_OF_GIVEN_PERSON = "//tr[contains(.,'%s')]";

public String getRowOfThePerson(String personName) {
    return String.format(ROW_OF_GIVEN_PERSON, personName);
}

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locators.getRowOfThePerson(personFullName)));
```

Where `%s` in xpath is replaced with `personName` given in parameter.

Comment: The effect is not the same. @FindBy annotation lets you use PageObject pattern powered by Selenium mechanisms which allow you to initialise the page elements using Java reflection.